# How to deal with graphql listgraphtypes that represent a sql relation

Tags: c#, graphql

The problem I am facing isn't very typical as I am trying to somehow make a generic graphql web api. I solved my issues based on some articles I found on the internet that I refactored to my needs. The thing is I am making a graphql api based on the database metadata, I have managed to create a root query, although the problem now is in the types. The workflow was to essentially loop through a collection that contains table names and columns add them to types/fields. The problem however is, that when I want to lets say query a child list I don't have the fields inside of the child which is from another type.

In essence:

```
query getCategoriesAndRelatedProducts {
 categories {
    categoryId
    productList {
      //productList got no fields
    }
  }
}
```

I am not doing a normal mapping from a model to a GraphType like this

```
public class ProductObject : ObjectGraphType<Product>
{
    private readonly IProductService product;

    public ProductObject(IProductService p)
    {
        product = p;
        Field(f => f.Id);
        Field(f => f.Name);
        FieldAsync<ProductTypeObject>("type",
            resolve: async context => await product.GetProductType(context.Source.Id));
    }
}
```

My Root Query is done in this fashion

```
public class NorthWindQuery : ObjectGraphType<object>
    {
        private readonly NorthWindContext _dbContext;
        private IDatabaseMetadata _dbMetadata;
        private ITableNameLookup _tableNameLookup;

        public NorthWindQuery(NorthWindContext dbContext, IDatabaseMetadata dbMetadata,
            ITableNameLookup tableNameLookup)
        {

            _dbMetadata = dbMetadata;
            _tableNameLookup = tableNameLookup;
            _dbContext = dbContext;


            foreach (var metaTable in _dbMetadata.GetTableMetadatas())
            {
                var tableType = new TableType(metaTable);
                var friendlyTableName = _tableNameLookup.GetFriendlyName(metaTable.TableName);

                AddField(new FieldType
                {
                    Name = friendlyTableName,
                    Type = tableType.GetType(),
                    ResolvedType = tableType,
                    Resolver = new MyFieldResolver(metaTable, _dbContext),
                    Arguments = new QueryArguments(
                        tableType.TableArgs
                    )
                });

                // lets add key to get list of current table
                var listType = new ListGraphType(tableType);
                AddField(new FieldType
                {
                    Name = $"{friendlyTableName}_list",
                    Type = listType.GetType(),
                    ResolvedType = listType,
                    Resolver = new MyFieldResolver(metaTable, _dbContext),
                    Arguments = new QueryArguments(
                        tableType.TableArgs
                    )
                });
            }
```

And the TableType is done like this:

```
public class TableType : ObjectGraphType<object>
    {
        public TableType (TableMetadata tableMetadata)
        {
            Name = tableMetadata.TableName;
            foreach (var tableColumn in tableMetadata.Columns)
            {
                InitGraphTableColumn(tableColumn);
            }
            TableArgs.Add(new QueryArgument<IdGraphType> { Name = "id" });
            TableArgs.Add(new QueryArgument<IntGraphType> { Name = "first" });
            TableArgs.Add(new QueryArgument<IntGraphType> { Name = "offset" });
            TableArgs.Add(new QueryArgument<StringGraphType> { Name = "includes" });
        }
        public QueryArguments TableArgs
        {
            get; set;
        }

        private IDictionary<string, Type> _databaseTypeToSystemType;
        protected IDictionary<string, Type> DatabaseTypeToSystemType
        {
            get
            {
                if (_databaseTypeToSystemType == null)
                {
                    _databaseTypeToSystemType = new Dictionary<string, Type>
                    {
                         { "uniqueidentifier", typeof(String) },
                        { "char", typeof(String) },
                        { "nvarchar", typeof(String) },
                        { "int", typeof(int) },
                        { "decimal", typeof(decimal) },
                        { "bit", typeof(bool) }
                    };
                }
                return _databaseTypeToSystemType;
            }
        }

        private void InitGraphTableColumn(ColumnMetadata columnMetadata)
        {
            var graphQLType = ResolveColumnMetaType(columnMetadata.DataType).GetGraphTypeFromType(true);
            var columnField = Field(
                graphQLType,
                columnMetadata.ColumnName
            );

            columnField.Resolver = new NameFieldResolver();
            FillArgs(columnMetadata.ColumnName);
        }

        private void FillArgs(string columnName)
        {
            if(TableArgs == null)
            {
                TableArgs = new QueryArguments(
                    new QueryArgument<StringGraphType>()
                    {
                        Name = columnName
                    });
            }
            else
            {
                TableArgs.Add(new QueryArgument<StringGraphType> { Name = columnName });
            }
        }

        private Type ResolveColumnMetaType(string dbType)
        {
            if (DatabaseTypeToSystemType.ContainsKey(dbType))
                return DatabaseTypeToSystemType[dbType];

            return typeof(String);
        }
```

Based on that I have only 1 tableType and 2 resolvers, tableType is the class that constructs the types,a and the 2 resolvers are used to translate graphql to queries and to return the value the NameFieldResolver and also the MyFieldResolver acts like a access to the orm.

If someone has done anything similar any help is welcome. I am doing this because I have a huge number of models and writing a direct mapping from a model is not an option cause I would have to write more then 10 thousand methods to get the api running.

Comment: Make it more clear, you need to post some code or unexpected result you get.

Answer (score 0):

I've worked with GraphQL but it was long time ago,
I'll give you a sample with One-Many relation (if I didn't get wrong you problem)
I have 2 models (Database Model)

```cs
public class ProductType
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name { get; set; } = "";
    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = "";
    public int ProductTypeId { get; set; }
    public virtual ProductType ProductType { get; set; }
}
```

They will be 2 type of GraphQL

```cs
public class ProductObject : ObjectGraphType<Product>
{
    private readonly IProductService product;
    public ProductObject(IProductService p)
    {
        product = p;
        Field(f => f.Id);
        Field(f => f.Name);
        FieldAsync<ProductTypeObject>("type",
            resolve: async context => await product.GetProductType(context.Source.Id));
    }
}

public class ProductTypeObject: ObjectGraphType<ProductType>
{
    private readonly IProductTypeService productType;
    public ProductTypeObject(IProductTypeService pT)
    {
        productType = pT;
        Field(f => f.Name);
        FieldAsync<ListGraphType<ProductObject>>("products",
            resolve: async context => await productType.GetProductsOfType(context.Source.Id));
    }
}
```

Explain it:
**IProductTypeService** and **IProductService** use to get data
**productType.GetProductsOfType(context.Source.Id)** will return **ICollection**
**await product.GetProductType(context.Source.Id)** will return **ProductType**

So you want to query 1 product type has many products it would be:

```
query getProductTypes {
   productTypes{
        id,
        name,
        products {
             id,
             name
        }        
   }
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the input but I am not doing a mapping from my models directly to a GraphType, I am using a foreach loop to loop thorough a collection that holds all Tablenames and ColumnNames, and essentially in the root query I am constructing them on the fly. I am doing that because I have a really huge ammount of models and mapping 1 to 1 isn't easy.

Comment: Oh, I've tried this before but not found the solution yet. So I hope someone can solve this question. Marked.

Comment: I have expanded my question now perhaps now you can understand what I try to solve.

Answer (score 0):

So after some time of thoughts and debugging it came to my mind that I am missing a crucial step in my approach. I haven't been treating the the relation as a GraphType so everything that I done was essentially not useful. So in theory lets imagine the simplest scenario possible:

```
type Character {
  name: String!
  appearsIn: [Episode]!
}
```

A Character is ObjectGraphType, but appearsIn is a ListGraphType(it can be also a ObjectGraphType depending on the Type) of Type Episode ObjectGraphType. So the appearsIn has all the fields that can be also found in Episode Type.

Which brings me to here I'll do some pseudo just that if someone reads this gets a understading of what to do next, in the TableType:

```
public class TableType : ObjectGraphType<object>
    {
        public TableType (TableMetadata tableMetadata)
        {
            Name = tableMetadata.TableName;
            foreach (var tableColumn in tableMetadata.Columns)
            {
                InitGraphTableColumn(tableColumn);
            }
            TableArgs.Add(new QueryArgument<IdGraphType> { Name = "id" });
            TableArgs.Add(new QueryArgument<IntGraphType> { Name = "first" });
            TableArgs.Add(new QueryArgument<IntGraphType> { Name = "offset" });
            TableArgs.Add(new QueryArgument<StringGraphType> { Name = "includes" });
        }
        public QueryArguments TableArgs
        {
            get; set;
        }

        private IDictionary<string, Type> _databaseTypeToSystemType;
        protected IDictionary<string, Type> DatabaseTypeToSystemType
        {
            get
            {
                if (_databaseTypeToSystemType == null)
                {
                    _databaseTypeToSystemType = new Dictionary<string, Type>
                    {
                         { "uniqueidentifier", typeof(String) },
                        { "char", typeof(String) },
                        { "nvarchar", typeof(String) },
                        { "int", typeof(int) },
                        { "decimal", typeof(decimal) },
                        { "bit", typeof(bool) }
                    };
                }
                return _databaseTypeToSystemType;
            }
        }

        private void InitGraphTableColumn(ColumnMetadata columnMetadata)
        {

        //here check with a if statement is the column.field a object
        // if it is a object make a new fieldtype based on that object
        // pass a resolver to the field
            var graphQLType = ResolveColumnMetaType(columnMetadata.DataType).GetGraphTypeFromType(true);
            var columnField = Field(
                graphQLType,
                columnMetadata.ColumnName
            );

            columnField.Resolver = new NameFieldResolver();
            FillArgs(columnMetadata.ColumnName);
        }

        private void FillArgs(string columnName)
        {
            if(TableArgs == null)
            {
                TableArgs = new QueryArguments(
                    new QueryArgument<StringGraphType>()
                    {
                        Name = columnName
                    });
            }
            else
            {
                TableArgs.Add(new QueryArgument<StringGraphType> { Name = columnName });
            }
        }

        private Type ResolveColumnMetaType(string dbType)
        {
            if (DatabaseTypeToSystemType.ContainsKey(dbType))
                return DatabaseTypeToSystemType[dbType];

            return typeof(String);
        }
```

So in essence a graph can have a name,fields, and a resolver, but the field can be of a another type, and while creating a type we can simply invoke a creation of a field which is from another type, and we have our relation that is a child relation that is from the type we need, and gain access to the fields of that type.

```
 private void InitGraphTableColumn(ColumnMetadata columnMetadata)
        {

        //here check with a if statement is the column.field a object
        // if it is a object make a new fieldtype based on that object
        // pass a resolver to the field
            var graphQLType = ResolveColumnMetaType(columnMetadata.DataType).GetGraphTypeFromType(true);
```

This is the part which is vital.